# Microeconomics Tax incident: unit tax imposed to consumer or producer

Tags: economics

I come up with a thought that if there is any difference in term of imposing a tax to consumer or producer, I searched for the answer and there is some logic messing up..

let Pd be the consumer price; and Ps be the producer price
Suppose the Unit Tax imposes to consumer, so in equilibrium: **Pd=Ps+t**
since the consumer now is paying extra t dollars than the producer receive.

On the other hand, Suppose the unit tax imposes to producer, so in equilibrium: **Ps+t=Pd** since the producer now is paying extra t than its originally pay

Now the question is, **why two formulas are identical**?
So is there any difference impose unit tax in terms of consumer or producer?
...or  I did something wrong with my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: That would depend on the behaviour of the producer(s) and customer(s). It could be that they are not entirely rational.

Answer (score 0):

The two formulas should be the same.  If the consumer pays the tax, he pays Pd to the producer and t to the government, so as you say Ps=Pd+t.  If the producer pays the tax, he collects Ps from the consumer and remits t to the government, giving Ps-t=Pd.  Why should it be any different?  The government is collecting t either way.